# how to create a PDF doc with the PDF content returned from a REST API

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob, jspdf, pdf.js

I am calling a REST API from the browser which gives me just the PDF content. The content-type in the response header of the API is "application/pdf".

I need to create a PDF document with this content and I should be able to open the PDF doc in a new tab and I should be able to download the PDF as well. How can I do this on UI. Do we have any JS library which would help me with this ? I have looked into JSPdf and PDF.js libraries but not sure whether these are the ones I can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pdfmake** its a great library and you can open, download, and print pdf. check it out [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)

**The steps**

First you define the content of the pdf in a certain JSON format:

```
    var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    { text: 'This is a header', style: 'header' },
    'No styling here, this is a standard paragraph',
    { text: 'Another text', style: 'anotherStyle' },
    { text: 'Multiple styles applied', style: [ 'header', 'anotherStyle' ] }
  ],

  styles: {
    header: {
      fontSize: 22,
      bold: true
    },
    anotherStyle: {
      italics: true,
      alignment: 'right'
    }
  }
};
```

**download**

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
```

**open**

```
var win = window.open('', '_blank');
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open({}, win);
```

**print**

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the content from a restAPI in the format of application/PDF. Can I pass such kind of content as well in order to create the PDF doc or is just text/html ?